# How to extract specific symbol from text in R

Tags: r, string, extract

I'm setting up a new project in R ,and want to extract specific symbol from text

```
X <- c("amazing tiny phone ^_^","so cute!!! <3")
```

I would like to extract  `^_^` and `<3` from `X` in R

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More straightforward

```
X = c("amazing tiny phone ^_^","so cute!!! <3","^_^ and :) are my fav symbols")
    patt=c("=d" ,"<3" , ":o" , ":(" ,
    ":)" , "(y)" , ":*" , "^_^", ":d" ,";)" , ":'(") 

variable = sapply(X,function(x){
                    i = which(patt%in%strsplit(x," ")[[1]])
                    if (length(i)>0){
                        paste(patt[i],collapse=" ")
                                    } else{NA}
          })

names(variable)=NULL

> variable
[1] "^_^"    "<3"     ":) ^_^" NA
```

Comment: I would like to extract any of these symbols =d ,<3 , :o , :( , :) , (y) , :* , ^_^ , :d , ;) , :'( if found in text

Comment: added a more straightforward approach, also considering multiple appearances of different symbols

Comment: no problem - if this answers your questions, please mark it as accepted answer to close the topic **edit** also watch out, I modified the code a bit so it correctly accounts for strings without any symbol!

Comment: Sorry but if i just need to return the symbol to put it in a variable not the whole text what should i do ?

Comment: for (value in docs) {
   variable = sapply(value,function(x){ 
     i = which(patt%in%strsplit(x," ")[[1]])
     if (length(i)>0){
       paste(patt[i],collapse=" ")
     } else{NA}
   })
   
   names(variable)=NULL
   variable
 } docs is a vector and i need to extract symbols from each text in vector but it didn't word

Answer (score 0):

@GraemeForst  A generalization could be achieved using groupings and lookaheads:

```
group <- "[\\^\\_\\<\\>3\\:\\(\\)\\;]"
pat <- sprintf(".*[\\s\\b](%s+)(?!\\1)", group)
```

- `group` defines the character grouping. Basically all symbols we want to extract.
- `pat` defines our matching pattern. The `[\\s\\b]` says prior to a possible match there must be either a blank or the boundary. And `(?!\\1)` say after a match there cannot be an element of `group`.

Here is a demo:

```
X <- c("amazing tiny phone ^_^","so cute!!! <3", "I like pizza :)", "hello beautiful ;)")
gsub(pat, "\\1", grep(pat, X, value = TRUE, perl = TRUE), perl = TRUE)
# [1] "^_^" "<3"  ":)"  ";)"
```

This can be further refined and generalized. An very simple step one can add is to extend the `grouping`.

---

**Old Answer**

You can use regex for this:

```
# create the pattern to be extracted
pat = ".*(\\^\\_\\^).*|.*(\\<3).*"  # escape special characters with "\\" and ".*" to specify there may be text before/after

# extract
gsub(pat, "\\1\\2", grep(pat, X, value = TRUE, perl = TRUE), perl = TRUE)
# [1] "^_^" "<3"
```

Comment: Is there a more general way to do this? I was wondering whether you could find all "words" that didn't have letters in them, using a pattern like `"[a-zA-Z]+"`